# Does the buildpath needs to reconfigured on local machine for a project checked-out through SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, selenium-webdriver

This is my first time using SVN or for that matter any version control. So, I've been able to check out a selenium project on my local machine. This source code was working fine on the other machine(my friend's), but on my machine it throws hundreds of errors such as *"BeforeClass cannot be resolved to a type, Assert cannot be resolved to a type"* etc.

I do know that this error could be because the required selenium jars may not have been setup in the build path. But, I can see all these selenium jars in the "lib" folder.

So, I want to understand if I need to reconfigure the build path. By the way, don't the project settings etc come by default as the same code works perfectly on other machine, which means the build path must have been configured there.

I know its a very basic question, but I assure you that I'm a naive coder.

Thanks for your help.

Note: I'm using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse's project configuration files (eg, `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings`, etc) are designed to be checked in with the rest of the project. If done so, whenever the project is checked out to a workspace Eclipse will automatically use them to properly configure the project. Check that your friend checked in those files; if not, ask him to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not add Eclipse project metadata files(.project,.classpath) & .settings folder to your source control system, so Eclipse doesn't know what your build path is or whether it is even a java project.

Go back to your other computer and look for the following files in your original project root...

.project
.classpath
.settings/*

Make sure all are present in Source Control System.